# C# beginner array

Tags: c#, arrays

A few weeks ago I began studying a c# beginners course, I got stuck on Arrays.
I do not want the complete answer for my problem, I want the tools or links to figure it out of myself

I´am trying to make a console Application that acts like a "Weather Station". 
The program should take user input as an array on how many measurements have been made (Done). After that the user will enter the degrees in an loop (Done)

The program should write out all the measurements and the average measurement.

I can calculate the average but don't know how to print the results

I've come this far...

```
   Console.WriteLine("How many measurements have you done");
   string str = Console.ReadLine();
   int size = Convert.ToInt32(str);

   int[] temperatur = new int[size];
   for (int i = 0; i < temperatur.Length; i++)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Enter temperature " + i + ": ");
       str = Console.ReadLine();
       int element = Convert.ToInt32(str);
       temperatur[i] = element;

   }
   Console.WriteLine("");
   int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < temperatur.Length; i++)
       sum = sum + temperatur[i];
  Console.WriteLine("The average temperature is " +
                      sum / temperatur.Length);
```

Comment: You have all the measurements in an array - and you're already iterating through that array. Just add another `Console.WriteLine` to the loop where you're summing up the temperatures.

Comment: What do you want to print ?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("Measurement {0} is {1}", i+1, temperatur[i];`

Comment: Thanks alot to all of you. I did solve the problem! Can i upvote your answer or do something for you guys let me now.

Comment: I made my above comment into an answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you state that the only problem you are having is 'print out all the measurements', all you have to do is add an additional `Console.WriteLine()` to the existing `for loop` you already have. You will also to have to add braces. As such:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < temperatur.Length; i++){
    sum = sum + temperatur[i];
    Console.WriteLine("Measurement {0} is {1}", i+1, temperatur[i]);
}
Console.WriteLine("The average temperature is " + sum / temperatur.Length);
```

You might not recognise that `Console.WriteLine()`, but it's basically a neat way of formatting your output using placeholders. The `{0}` will be replaced with the first value provided, the `{1}` with the second.

EDIT: MSDN documentation on [`Console.WriteLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx) and also [`String.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: As a beginner, additional suggested reading regarding [`Console.WriteLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aakt1eab%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`String.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Oh i see. Thanks again i solved the problem with the earlier answer from you. Big thanks for the explanations of the {0} {1] value. Now the pieces are falling into place!

Comment: I will certainly do that Bernd. 
And thanks for the links Scott. I have been able to solve some previous problems with the MSDN documentation. And i will keep using that and "googling" but it´s nice to see a forum with such expertise and fast response!

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < temperatur.Length; i++)
        sum = sum + temperatur[i]; 
    Console.WriteLine("The average temperature is " + sum / temperatur.Length);
```

Change this to :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < temperatur.Length; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + temperatur[i]; 
        Console.WriteLine("Temperature {0} is {1}", i, temperatur[i]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("The average temperature is " + sum / temperatur.Length);
```

Comment: Cheers man, i complete forgot to add the ´Console.WriteLine("Temperature {0} is {1}", i, temperatur[i]);´  inside my for loop. Thanks Fabjan, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in the same for:

```
for (int i = 0; i < temperatur.Length; i++) 
{
    sum = sum + temperatur[i];
    Console.WriteLine("Temperature {0}", temperatur[i]);
}

Console.WriteLine("The average temperature is " + sum / temperatur.Length);
```

In another statement:

```
for (int i = 0; i < temperatur.Length; i++) 
{
    sum = sum + temperatur[i];
}

temperatur.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine("Temperature {0}", x));

Console.WriteLine("The average temperature is " + sum / temperatur.Length);
```

Comment: I will test that later on and see how that affects my code. And lookup more about .Foreach example. 
Thank you for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score -1):

```
object[] objects = { "hello", 123, true };
for (int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(objects[i].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Are you affiliated with the site you are linking to? Please review [How to not be a spammer.](/help/promotion)

Answer (score -2):

...

```
Console.WriteLine("The average temperature is " + sum / temperatur.Length);
Console.ReadLine();
```

In the end type `Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: Cheers man, i did solve the problem with the answers above. Thanks for you time!